# How to get number of commits from a public organization repo in Github

Tags: git, github

Looking to get number of commits from a public repo that is an organization. I attempted to use the url:https://api.github.com/repos/bitcoin/bitcoin/stats/contributors and it seems like this link is for users. Not entirely sure why it is not working correctly.

I have used the same formatted link on another github repo and it seems to work:
https://api.github.com/repos/cms-sw/cmssw/stats/contributors

Comment: The `Insights` tab on the repo's page doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: So after looking at the insights it seems to be that a lot of the information isnt working as well. Could this be an issue on github's end with no solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Github docs on this topic](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#a-word-about-caching), gathering the repositories stats is an expensive operation, so the data is cached.

It returns an empty object with a `202` response code if there's no data cached, and a job to generate the stats for this repository is queued. You'll get a response code `200` if you repeat your request  once the job has finished. I believe this is the behavior you were encountering.

I have tried with a few (small) private repositories and the stats were generated in seconds, although it may take significantly longer for repositories with a huge commit history or a large number of contributors.